# Macbook mid-2010: no power after ssd upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, charging, logicboard

I changed my HDD to a SSD using [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Remplacement+du+SSD+dans+le+MacBook+Unibody+mod%C3%A8le+A1342/1670) guide on my MacBook Unibody Model A1342 (mid-2010).

But after reconnecting the battery, the Mac seems to be dead (MagSafe light off, no chime, no fan, nothing). I tried another charger that works perfectly with another Mac with no success.

Any chance that this is "only" a battery issue? Or has the logic board died? Is there any other possible solution?

EDIT: Finally, I changed the logic board and the Macbook is back to life...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No light on a MagSafe adapter means it's not seeing the (one wire) charging circuit of your MacBook Pro.

So, this is unfortunately not a battery issue.  It's further confirmed by no fan spin and the fact that you eliminated the charger from the equation by testing it (successfully) on a different computer.

You may have shorted something during your swap or it could be just coincidence.  However, there are a couple of things to check before resigning it's a logic board issue:

- [check/clean your MagSafe port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49790/119271).  It could be just coincidence that your MagSafe port is dirty/blocked and preventing you from powering/charging your MacBook
- double check your connections; you may have missed one or more or may have accidentally disconnected something.
- [check your DC In board](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195062/119271). It's a relatively inexpensive part that's fairly easy to swap out.  If anything was going to "go" this would be the most likely part

Comment: Thanks for the first leads. I should add that the battery was full just before I disconnected it.

Comment: You don't need a battery to run a Macbook, disconnect it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Assuming you've double checked all your connections, my next step would be to diagnose the DC In board.  After that, it would be time to look at the logic board for a failure.

Comment: This part seems to be more tricky but ok... Is there a way to diagnose it before buying the part?

Comment: Easiest and safest way is to swap it out with a known working one.  It's cheap enough that you can do it with this part.   Used ones on eBay go for around $10 USD